# Some misunderstanding on Hamilton's paper "Three-fold with positive Ricci curvature"

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Now I am reading the Hamilton's paper named "Three-fold with positive Ricci curvature ". In the section 8 " curvature in dimension three ", he introduces a new tensor $Q_{ij}$ and followed by Theorem 8.3. The theorem states that

" The tensor $Q_{ij}$ vanishes identically on any three dimensional symmetric Riemannian manifold. Any symmetric tensor $T_{ij}$ which is quadratic in the Ricci curvature and has the property must be a scalar multiple of $Q_{ij}$."

I don't really understand what the term "quadratic" in this scenarios means. Anyone can explain it for me? thank you.

Comment: In the absence of any other clues, I'd wager that Hamilton calls $T_{ij}$ quadratic in the Ricci curvature (whose components I denote by) $R_{ij}$ if, when $R_{ij}\mapsto \lambda R_{ij}$ ($\lambda \in \Bbb R$), $T_{ij}\mapsto \lambda^2 T_{ij}$.